# Ansible shell task with pgrep keeps failing, works in normal shell

Tags: bash, ssh, grep, ansible

I'm on `ansible-2.0.1.0-2.el7.noarch` (but tried with `1.9.4` as well) and I'm trying to run this playbook:

```
- hosts: all
  remote_user: root
  tasks:
    - shell:
        pgrep --full 'sleep' && pkill --full 'sleep' || true
```

but I'm getting:

```
# ansible-playbook -i aaa.ini aaa.yaml 

PLAY ***************************************************************************

TASK [setup] *******************************************************************
ok: [192.168.122.100]

TASK [command] *****************************************************************
fatal: [192.168.122.100]: FAILED! => {"changed": true, "cmd": "pgrep --full 'sleep' && pkill --full 'sleep' || true", "delta": "0:00:00.158772", "end": "2016-05-05 00:33:49.072139", "failed": true, "rc": -15, "start": "2016-05-05 00:33:48.913367", "stderr": "", "stdout": "385", "stdout_lines": ["385"], "warnings": []}

NO MORE HOSTS LEFT *************************************************************
    to retry, use: --limit @aaa.retry

PLAY RECAP *********************************************************************
192.168.122.100               : ok=1    changed=0    unreachable=0    failed=1
```

When I run the command directly, it works:

```
host # ssh root@192.168.122.100
vm # pgrep --full 'sleep' && pkill --full 'sleep' || true
vm # echo $?
0
```

Please do you have any idea on what I'm doing wrong?

**UPDATE** as per @Dag's answer bellow which deciphered this for me:

```
$ ansible localhost -m shell -a "pgrep --list-full -f process_that_does_not_exists"
localhost | SUCCESS | rc=0 >>
828 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/ansible localhost -m shell -a pgrep --list-full -f process_that_does_not_exists
835 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/ansible localhost -m shell -a pgrep --list-full -f process_that_does_not_exists
836 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/ansible localhost -m shell -a pgrep --list-full -f process_that_does_not_exists
```

so the command with `&& pkill ...` was actually killing some Ansible's processes. Looks like I have to add some more filtering to make this work safely.

Comment: I have no idea, but it seems unnecessary to do both a pgrep and a pkill. If the pgrep would fail because there are no tasks, then the pkill will do nothing, which is correct. If there are tasks, pgrep will find them, and pkill will look again for the same tasks and kill them. "Test and then act" is an antipattern because of the race conditions: what happens if a pgrep finds nothing and then a task starts which would have been killed by pkill? Or pgrep finds a tasks and it dies before pkill runs?

Comment: can you please run command as follows: `set -x; pgrep --full 'sleep' && pkill --full 'sleep' || true`

Comment: @rici In my case sleep is not running, but I used this pattern for something meaningful. But you are right `pkill --full 'sleep' || true` might be sufficient.

Comment: @Samuel `# ansible -i aaa.ini -m shell -a "set -x; pgrep --full 'sleep' && pkill --full 'sleep' || true" all
172.21.0.151 | FAILED | rc=-15 >>
110+ pgrep --full sleep
+ pkill --full sleep`

Comment: I mean from command line :)

Comment: @Samuel Already pasted very similar output in question, but with `set -x` now: `# set -x; pgrep --full 'sleep' && pkill --full 'sleep' || true; echo $?
+ pgrep --full sleep
+ true
+ echo 0
0`

Comment: @rici I have tried what you have suggested but it fails as well: `failed: [192.168.122.100] => {"changed": true, "cmd": "pkill --full '/usr/bin/goferd' || true", "delta": "0:00:00.136384", "end": "2016-05-06 14:55:53.998328", "rc": -15, "start": "2016-05-06 14:55:53.861944", "warnings": []}`

Comment: @jhutar: yes, I didn't think it would solve your underlying problem. It is possibly a permissions issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What is very apparent from your output is that the command returns -15.
Which means the process was terminated.

If I execute your command on localhost, I am actually killing my own ansible run.

```
[dag@moria ~]$ ansible localhost -m shell -a 'pgrep -f 'sleep' && pkill -f 'sleep' || true'
Terminated
```

So you are doing the same from a playbook, and are killing part of Ansible's processes, but not too many so it can properly report back some output and the return code. (I was actually killing the main calling process on my own system too !)

Comment: Wow, thank you. Have to investigate this a bit. I was searching for what rc -15 means but were unsuccessful. Do you know about some docs?

Comment: You are exactly right. Added `pgrep --list-full ...` output to the question. Also running with `ps aux` helped me to learn about Ansible's processes. Thank you for revealing this mystery for me.

Comment: Just for a record, this works as I need: `pkill --full --exact 'sleep 100' || true`. It is not that flexible (you need exact command line), but works and does not touches Ansible processes.

Answer (score 1):

Ansible's shell module runs the script as (or equivalent to)

`bash -c "your-whole-script-as-one-quoted-string"`

So if your script contains `pkill -f killpattern` it's going to match not only the process(es) you meant to kill but also the shell process running the pkill command -- i.e. the ansible step itself.

To get around this, you need to do something like this:

`for i in $(pgrep -f killpattern | grep -v -x $$) ; do kill $i ; done`

Answer (score 1):

I was hitting a similar issue, and fixed it by putting the script into .sh file and execute `sh xxx.sh`.

Just a heads up, it might be the best practice to use `script` or `command` module instead of the `shell` one in ansible: [Notes - shell - Execute commands in nodes](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.7/modules/shell_module.html#notes)